# Do magical items have set quests?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Do any magic items have set quests where you always find them, or does the DM reward them based on monsters and levels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are true.  Pre-written adventures generally have treasure and magic items written into the adventure, so for those, every party that goes through that adventure will find the same things, and those items (at least the unusual/unique ones) will be tied to that module/quest.  For adventuring in which the DM has not purchased a pre-written adventure (or who has one but modifies it significantly), DM discretion according to monsters, according to levels, according to DMG guidelines for treasure encountered, are all ways to apportion items in a reasonable and balanced way.